# Spelling Game using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have provided a list of words that will randomly be picked for the game. What it does is to prompt the player to enter an alphabet of the selected word. If the letter provided by the users is found in the selected word, they if be asked if they want to attempt spelling the whole word. if they say yes, then they will be able to do so. Else, they will have to try entering another alphabet.how do I get the output/ results of each user input to be printed as (eg: Outcome: a------) And if the users ended up saying yes to spelling the whole word, how should they be prompt to enter the word? 
eg: Do you want spell the word now? (y/n): y 
Spell the complete word:
You are correct! 
The correct word is albumen 
Spell another word? (y/n): y

```
import random

wordList = ('apple', 'albumen', 'toothpaste', 'enthusiastic')

word = random.choice(wordList)

letter_guess = ""

word_guess = ""

store_letter = ""

count = 1

limit = 5

countLetters = len(word)

choice1 = ("Do you want to spell the word now? (y/n):")

choice2 = ("Spell another word? (y/n):")

choiceY = ("y")

choiceN = ("n")



startGame = print("The word ________ has {} letters. Spell it in 5 tries.".format(countLetters))

while count < limit:
    letter_guess = input("Try {} - Current: ________. Your guess? ".format(count))

    if letter_guess in word:
        print ("yes")
        print (input(choice1))

    else :
        print("no")
        count += 1

    if choice1 == choiceY:
        print (input("Spell the complete word: "))

    else:
        print (letter_guess)
        store_letter += letter_guess
        count += 1


while count == limit:
    spellFinal = input("Spell the complete word: ")

    if spellFinal in word:
        print ("You are correct!")
        print ("Spell another word? (y/n):")

    if choice == "y":
        print (startGame)

    else:
        print('Remaining Words are: ', store_letter)

    if spellFinal not in word:
        print ("You are incorrect")
        print ("The correct word is {}.".format(correct))
```

[image: Output example]

[image: Snippet of my code]

Comment: What is you question?

Comment: Hi, Apologies, missed the question out. What I want to know is how do I get the output/ results of each user input to be printed as (eg: Outcome: a------)

Comment: and if the users ended up saying yes to spelling the whole word, how should they be prompt to enter the word?
 eg: Do you want spell the word now? (y/n): y
Spell the complete word: albumen
You are correct!
The correct word is albumen
Spell another word? (y/n): y

Comment: Hi, no worries. Please add the actual question to the body of your question post.

Answer (score 0):

You are not collecting the information from your `print (input(choice1))` line. You should be assigning it to a variable to be able to compare it later with your `choiceY` (or you could simply compare the new variable to "y" without having a choiceY variable defined, up to you).

For example:

```
user_choice = ""
complete_word = ""

if letter_guess in word:
    print ("yes\n")
    user_choice = input(choice1)
    if user_choice.lower() is "y":
        complete_word = input("Spell the complete word: ")
        #here you compare complete_word with your word variable
    else:
        print (letter_guess)
        store_letter += letter_guess
        count += 1
else:
    print("no\n")
    count +=1
```

The same applies to the other sections of you code that have the `print(input(...))`.
Nested ifs can get messy. Perhaps you can consider having a verification function and call that instead.

Hope this helps!